# jQuery/JS/p5 - create a website that collapses when scrolling

Tags: text, scroll

Sorry for being so vague, but I don't know where to start.

Basically I want to create website inspired by Neo-TOkyo from AKIRA manga.

When entering the site the visitor will see two columns of text with images behind them.

When scrolling down, both text and images should start collapsing/falling down to the bottom of the page.

Quick mock up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx9Yt.jpg

once everything is down, a button to purchase the t-shirt should appear in the middle of the page.

Is this possible to accomplish?

Comment: The answer would be yes. What exactly is your question?
Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where can I look for tutorials? I don't even know how to formulate a question about such a feature. I assume it'd be jquery?